# Convolution identity in Schwartz space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I met a convolution identity in section 7.4, page 185, Functional Analysis by Rudin, which I cannot justify .

$$(P(D)f)*e^{itx}=f*P(D)e^{itx}$$

where $D$ is differential operator and $P(D)=\sum_{\alpha} c_{\alpha}i^{-|\alpha|}D^{\alpha}$ and $f\in\mathscr{S}(R^{n})$. I know $P(D)e^{itx}=P(t)e^{itx}$.

Comment: Integration by parts ($|\alpha|$ times).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for this tip. But I am not clear why the constant term from differentiation by parts is $0$? The problem is that $e^{itx}$ is unbounded at infinity.

Comment: No it's not unbounded at infinity! It's bounded by $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $g(x)=e^{it\cdot x}$.
$$
\begin{align}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\partial_kf(y)\,g(x-y)\,\mathrm{d}y
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}f(y)\,g(x-y)\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=-\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)\,\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}g(x-y)\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)\,\partial_kg(x-y)\,\mathrm{d}y\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for this tip. But why the constant term from integration by parts is equal to $0$? That is why $f(+\infty)e^{it(x-\infty)}-f(-\infty)e^{it(x+\infty)}=0$? I know $f(x)$ decays to $0$ at infinity, but $e^{itx}$ is unbounded at infinity.

Comment: @Hua ??? $|e^{itx}|=1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh, sorry for this question. I get it. So this identity only holds for special $g(x)$, not for general cases.